# Ansible Playbook adding the same line multiple times to yml file

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have to add the same line several times in the same file. It must always be inserted after a certain line, which is the same for both locations.
I have tried it with the `lineinfile` module, but, there, only one line is always added. I have also tried with the `replace` module, but, then, no line is added at all.

My `lineinfile` task looks like this:

```yaml
- name: Add Line
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile: 
    path: someyml.yml
    insertbefore: "template:"
    line: "{{ Cluster_API}}"
```

The `replace` task looks like this:

```yaml
- name: Replace
  replace:
    path: someyml.yml
    regexp: '^(template:\n)(?!{{ Cluster_API }})'
    replace: '\1 {{ Cluster_API }}\n'
```

I know how the replace is written it should insert a line after `template:` but it doesn't even do that.

Comment: `lineinfile` won't indeed help you with your requirement: [_This is primarily useful when you want to change a single line in a file only. See the ansible.builtin.replace module if you want to change multiple_](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#synopsis). Now, if your replace does not work, this is probably because the regex does not match. Could you share a snippet of the file _someyml.yml_ containing the `template:` line?

Comment: Also, please have a look at our [mre] page. Since, as written, your question fails to fulfil the _reproducible_ part of it, with the missing YAML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have tested with a test file:

```
abcdef
template:
toto

123
template:

ssss
template:
toto
```

playbook test:

```
- name: "tips3"
  hosts: localhost      
  tasks:
    - name: replace 'template:' not followed by toto by 'template:\ntoto'
      replace:
          path: files/test.txt
          regexp: '^(template:)(?!\n{{data}})'
          replace: '\1\n{{data}}'
      vars:
        data: toto
```

result: just only one `toto` added after the second template

```
abcdef
template:
toto

123
template:
toto

ssss
template:
toto
```